# Can’t log out of iCloud on iPhone - ‘Verification Failed’

Tags: iphone, icloud

So when I try to sign out of iCloud on my iPhone, I get the message - enter password to turn off find my phone. After entering the password, a message comes up stating ‘Verification Failed - There was an error connecting to iCloud’.

What I’ve tried so far: 
1) Resetting all Network Setting, 
2) Changing Apple ID password.

Neither works! Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Forgive the obvious question, but is your iCloud account the same as your normal Apple ID? Many people have two accounts, one they use for iCloud and one they use for other purposes, such as the App Store, iTunes, etc. I've come across many people who forget this and try using their Apple ID password instead of their iCloud account password.

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this by making sure under cellular you have “settings” enabled. I didn’t have it toggled in and I was not on a wifi service when I was trying to log out of iCloud.

Comment: Small details that make the difference! Just connected to WiFi and logged out form the device. Thanks @Hosmoz

Answer (score 2):

Here's my advice:

- Check your date time settings. If you're on incorrect time, maybe this error appears. So please turn on "set time/date automatically" Settings > General > Date & Time > Set Automatically
- Are you using multiple accounts for iTunes, App Store, iCloud? Multiple accounts are can cause many problems
- If you're tried Reset Network Settings, then try again by different Wi-Fi connection.
- If you've enabled "iCloud Backup" on your iPhone, then turn it off and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone overlooked this.
There needs to be an internet connection in order to either turn 'Find My iPhone' off, or sign out of iCloud.

It is not uncommon to restore the device (it will not remember wifi passwords) and then erase it. In such case, you will need to connect to the internet first.